# Why I am having this type of error "TypeError: oColumn is undefined" using jquery datatables I followed all from its docs

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, datatables

Why I am having this type of error "TypeError: oColumn is undefined" using jquery datatables I followed all instructions from its docs. I dont know what is wrong?

Here's  the firebug's error output:

[image]

Here's my html table structure:

[image]

And here's the jquery code I use:

```
<style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
    @import "datatables/media/css/demo_table.css";
</style>
<script src="datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#products-result').dataTable( {
                "sDom": "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>"
            } );
            $.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
            "sWrapper": "dataTables_wrapper form-inline"
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

table generated by jquery:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'get-products.php',
        type: 'post',
        datatype: 'json',
        data: { category: $('.category').val().trim(), keyword: $('.keyword').val().trim() },
        beforeSend: fnLoadStart,
        complete: fnLoadStop,
        success: function(data){
            var toAppend = '';

            toAppend += '<thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Image</th><th>Price</th><th>Shipping</th><th>Weight</th><th>Dimension</th><th>ASIN</th><th>Description</th><th>Reviews</th><th>Category</th></tr></thead>';
            toAppend += '<tbody>';

            if(typeof data === "object"){
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

                    var price = '';
                    if(data[i]['price'] === null){
                        price = 'No Price Available';
                    }
                    else {
                        price = data[i]['price'][0];
                    }
                    var img = '';
                    if(data[i]['image'] === null){
                        img = '<img class="no-image" src="no-image.jpg" alt="">';
                    }
                    else {
                        img = '<img src="'+data[i]['image'][0]+'" alt="">';
                    }
                    var description = '';
                    if(data[i]['product_description'] == 'Not Available'){
                        description = data[i]['product_description'];
                    }
                    else {
                        description = data[i]['product_description'][0];
                    }

                    toAppend += 
                    '<tr><td><p>'+
                    data[i]['product_name'][0]+'</p></td><td>'+
                    img+'</td><td>'+
                    price+'</td><td><ul><li><span>Standard: </span>'+
                    data[i]['standard_shipping']+'</li><li><span>Expedited: </span>'+
                    data[i]['expedited_shipping']+'</li><li><span>Two-day: </span>'+
                    data[i]['twoday_shipping']+'</li><li><span>One-day: </span>'+
                    data[i]['oneday_shipping']+'</li></ul></td><td>'+
                    data[i]['weight']+'</td><td>'+
                    data[i]['dimension']+'</td><td>'+
                    data[i]['asin'][0]+'</td><td><p>'+
                    description+'</p></td><td><iframe src="'+
                    data[i]['reviews'][0]+'"></iframe></td><td>'+
                    data[i]['category'][0]+'</td></tr>';
                }

                toAppend += '</tbody>';

                $('.data-results').append(toAppend);
            }
        }
    });
```

The HTML table

```
<div>
    <table id="products-result" class="display data-results table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">

    </table>
</div>
```

Browser View Source:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Products</title>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/search.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
        @import "datatables/media/css/demo_table.css";
    </style>
    <script src="datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#products-result').dataTable( {
                    "sDom": "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>"
                } );
                $.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
                "sWrapper": "dataTables_wrapper form-inline"
            } );
        } );
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<div>

    <div class="span7">
        <form class="form-inline">
            <select class="category">x
                <option>All</option>
                <option>Apparel</option>
                <option>Appliances</option>
                <option>ArtsAndCrafts</option>
                <option>Automotive</option>
                <option>Baby</option>
                <option>Beauty</option>
                <option>Blended</option>
                <option>Books</option>
                <option>Classical</option>
                <option>Collectibles</option>
                <option>DVD</option>
                <option>DigitalMusic</option>
                <option>Electronics</option>
                <option>GiftCards</option>
                <option>GourmetFood</option>
                <option>Grocery</option>
                <option>HealthPersonalCare</option>
                <option>HomeGarden</option>
                <option>Industrial</option>
                <option>Jewelry</option>
                <option>KindleStore</option>
                <option>Kitchen</option>
                <option>LawnAndGarden</option>
                <option>Marketplace</option>
                <option>MP3Downloads</option>
                <option>Magazines</option>
                <option>Miscellaneous</option>
                <option>Music</option>
                <option>MusicTracks</option>
                <option>MusicalInstruments</option>
                <option>MobileApps</option>
                <option>OfficeProducts</option>
                <option>OutdoorLiving</option>
                <option>PCHardware</option>
                <option>PetSupplies</option>
                <option>Photo</option>
                <option>Shoes</option>
                <option>Software</option>
                <option>SportingGoods</option>
                <option>Tools</option>
                <option>Toys</option>
                <option>UnboxVideo</option>
                <option>VHS</option>
                <option>Video</option>
                <option>VideoGames</option>
                <option>Watches</option>
                <option>Wireless</option>
                <option>WirelessAccessories</option>
            </select>
            <input class="keyword" type="text" placeholder="Keyword">
            <input type="button" class="btnresult btn" value="Generate">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="ajaxLoader">
        <img src="loading.gif" alt="">
    </div>

    <div>
        <table id="products-result" class="display data-results table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">

        </table>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the html generated by your code? Like from View Source?

Comment: @hsalama, it's a bit messy thou, updated! :)

Comment: Can you copy from the generated code (from your browser view source) rather than your own code. I am interested to see the final structure of the table when the plugin is being applied.

Comment: Can you provide the link to the documentation example you followed?

Comment: @hsalama it that what you want?

Comment: Check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280900/typeerror-ocolumn-is-undefined-when-using-jquery-datatables-library

Comment: @JaredFarrish [DOCS](http://datatables.net/blog/Getting_started_with_DataTables%3a_First_steps)

Comment: @techfoobar, yes I already see that the answer was to follow proper table structure and I already followed that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, it looks like your table is empty on load, so `datatables` might not work since it is not formatted properly to start with. So, I'd suggest you build your table with a proper HTML first before you populate it via ajax. So try to make this

```
<div>
    <table id="products-result" class="display data-results table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Image</th><th>Price</th><th>Shipping</th><th>Weight</th><th>Dimension</th><th>ASIN</th><th>Description</th><th>Reviews</th><th>Category</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and then via your ajax do append to the `tbody`

Comment: it not working well, it says no data in table available even though I display the values and when I click it it didnt sort

Comment: it works now I just put my datatable function inside fnloadStop!,

Answer (score 18):

Hope this would help you all, at least to get a hint out of it.

http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/42607

My problem was, TypeError: col is undefined.

**Summarized Answer:**

> Number of TH elements within the TR element within the THead
>   element of the Table MUST BE EQUAL to the Number of TD elements(or
>   number of columns within your Table Rows) within the TR element(s) of
>   your TBody in the Table.

**You can read the explanation bellow:**

The problem was, I hadn't put enough Th or Td elements within the thead section to be equal to the number of columns which I print as Td elements inside the Tr elements within the TBody section.

Following code did give me the error.

```
<thead>
 <tr>
    <th> Heading 1</th>
    <th> Heading 2</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
    <td> Column 1 </td>
    <td> Column 2</td>
    <td> Column 3</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>"
```

But just adding one more Th element to the Tr element within the THead element made it works like a charm! :) And I got the hint from the above link.

And also, I found that all the TH elements within the THead's Tr element could be TD elements too, as it's also valid HTML to the required level by the jQuery DataTables!

Hope I helped some of you to save your time! :)

Comment: saved me a lot of time, thanks! I had the tally right, but hadn't put them in a thead and tbody

Comment: :-) you are mostly welcome!Glad to know,that it's helpful somebody!

Answer (score 1):

Problem I faced: TypeError: col is undefined.

please check two things in your table, this error can be due to any of below two reasons:

**Reason 1)** Number of TH & TD elements in the TRs are not matching, both count should be equal.

Ex: below table is wrong, because it have 2 TH and 3 TR

```
'<table>
<thead>
 <tr>
    <th> Field Caption 1</th>
    <th> Field Caption 2</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
    <td> Field Value 1 </td>
    <td> Field Value 2</td>
    <td> Field Value 3</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>`
```

**Reason 2)** You can face this problem if you are using 'colspan' & 'rowspan' in a table wrongly.

```
`<table>
<thead>
 <tr>
    <th> Field Caption 1</th>
    <th colspan="2"> Actions</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
    <td> Field Value 1 </td>
    <td> Edit</td>
    <td> Delete</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>`
```

**Try to remove or rectify "colspan" & "rowspan" and then try.**

Hope it would help.