# jQuery Datatable - TypeError: settings.aoColumns[column] is undefined whilst table is well formatted

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have an issue when openening the page containing the table.

I get this error message :

> TypeError: settings.aoColumns[column] is undefined

After some research on this message, It appears that this message pops up when the table is not well formatted.

Mine looks like this :

```
<table class="table datatable table-nns" id="table-nns-id">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th class="col-md-1"><?= $this->lang->line('something') ?></th>
               <th class="col-md-1"></th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
       <tbody> </tbody>
</table>
```

I can't figure out the reason because this table works on other pages...

Comment: The HTML you've got there looks fine (assuming the PHP output is correctly formatted). What content is within the `tbody`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: oColumn is undefined When Using jQuery Datatables Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280900/typeerror-ocolumn-is-undefined-when-using-jquery-datatables-library)

Comment: @AbhishekPandey Nope, I've seen that question, but that's the point of my question, My table is well formatted, I guess..

Comment: Are you using sever side option?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The content in tbody is populated dynamically, but it gets a tr and td's in it

Comment: It may well do, but that doesn't mean its valid HTML.

Comment: If the `tbody` is binding dynamically then you need to initialize table after data binding.